# Can we add pagination or lazy loading in ImageBrowser of Kendo Editor?

Tags: image, .net-core, kendo-ui, html-helper, kendo-editor

I am working with an application where I have thousands of images to load on ImageBrowser of Kendo Editor.

ImageBrowser is getting stuck as having too many images to load, **Can we have any option to add pagination or lazy loading in ImageBrowser?**

So, I can load only 20 images at a time and other based on request.

Please note that I am fetching images from controller method which returns list of FileBrowserEntry as below.

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Looking at the API documentation, I do not see where you can lazy load images let alone implement a pagination. Is all that you're trying to accomplish is to just implement an ImageBrowser or do you need the editor for something else? If it is the former, there might be better options in the Kendo-UI suite.

Comment: Thanks @David, Yes, I want editor with ImageBrowser.